# Setting TextField Focus on text removal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

i have four textfields. User is allowed to enter only one digit in each text field.Once the user Enters single digit its focus should be on the next textfield. i have done this part and its working fine. Now, What i want is when i remove the text from the text field then its focus should move to previous textfield. i mean if i am deleting the text(digit) from the fourth text field then its focus should move to third text field. In short on removal of text the focus should be on previous textfield.

Now, what my problem is when i remove the text from the textfield then its focus moves to previous textfield but it clears the text of that textfield(the textfield on which i have set the focus).What i want is the text should not be removed on focus.

```
in .h file

IBOutlet UITextField *txtPinDigit1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtPinDigit2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtPinDigit3;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtPinDigit4;
     UITextField *currentTextField;

in .m file

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.tag==0)
    {
        currentTextField=txtPinDigit1;
    }
    else if(textField.tag==1)
    {
        currentTextField=txtPinDigit2;
    }
    else if(textField.tag==2)
    {
        currentTextField=txtPinDigit3;
        if(isDelete)
        {
            textField.text=digit3;
        }
    }
    else if(textField.tag==3)
    {
        currentTextField=txtPinDigit4;
    }

    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if(([textField.text length]==1)&&(![string isEqualToString:@""]))
    {
        if(currentTextField==txtPinDigit1)
        {
            [txtPinDigit2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if(currentTextField==txtPinDigit2)
        {
            [txtPinDigit3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if(currentTextField==txtPinDigit3)
        {
            [txtPinDigit4 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if(currentTextField==txtPinDigit4)
        {
            textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH-1];
            //[txtPinDigit4 resignFirstResponder];
            //[txtPinDigit1 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    else if([string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        isDelete=YES;
        NSLog(@"replacementString:%@",string);
       // textField.text=string;
        if(currentTextField==txtPinDigit4)
        {
            textField.text=string;
            digit3=nil;
            [digit3 release];
            digit3=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",[txtPinDigit3.text intValue]];

            [txtPinDigit3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if(currentTextField==txtPinDigit3)
        {
            textField.text=string;
            [txtPinDigit2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if(currentTextField==txtPinDigit2)
        {
            textField.text=string;
            [txtPinDigit1 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if(currentTextField==txtPinDigit1)
        {
            textField.text=string;
           // [txtPinDigit1 resignFirstResponder];
            //[txtPinDigit1 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

in the above code MAXLENGTH=1 defined.

any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This code, Change shouldChangeCharactersInRange: Delegate Method

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if ([newString length] < 1) 
    {

        if (textField.tag==2)
        {
            [txtPinDigit1 performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
            //            txt2.text=@"";
        }
        else if (textField.tag==3)
        {

            [txtPinDigit2 performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
        else if (textField.tag==4)
        {
            [txtPinDigit3 performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

        }
        return YES;
    } else
    {
        // Otherwise we cut the length of newString to 1 (if needed) and set it to the textField.
        textField.text = [newString length] > 1 ? [newString substringToIndex:1] : newString;

        if (textField.tag==1)
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            [txtPinDigit2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if (textField.tag==2)
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            [txtPinDigit3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if (textField.tag==3)
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            [txtPinDigit4 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        return NO;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to check length via this way and put a break point at beginning of shouldChangeCharactersInRange

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
       int length = textField.text.length - range.length + string.length;

       return YES;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: hi chandan, its unchecked only, the problem is when setting the textfield as become first responder. It is automatically clearing it.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and change in shouldChangeCharactersInRange method. Please let me know if still any problem occurs. Thanks

Comment: It is due to shouldChangeCharactersInRange method . Please print  string value also before else if([string isEqualToString:@""]) to check its working fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling up to become first responder on filling up the 1st digit,bind the entered text inputs & the responder into dictionary...

On each previous/next condition,retrieve the information from the dictionary...The below example code is for the general previous/next custom actions(not auto though)..You just need to change the logic a bit based on the condition you prefer...

```
- (NSArray *) responders
{
    if (_responders)
        return _responders;

    NSArray *textInputs = EditableTextInputsInView([[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]);
    return [textInputs sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIView *textInput1, UIView *textInput2) {
        UIView *commonAncestorView = textInput1.superview;
        while (commonAncestorView && ![textInput2 isDescendantOfView:commonAncestorView])
            commonAncestorView = commonAncestorView.superview;

        CGRect frame1 = [textInput1 convertRect:textInput1.bounds toView:commonAncestorView];
        CGRect frame2 = [textInput2 convertRect:textInput2.bounds toView:commonAncestorView];
        return [@(CGRectGetMinY(frame1)) compare:@(CGRectGetMinY(frame2))];
    }];
}
```

The below function should get called before doing previous/next auto tab.

```
- (Void) selectAdjacentResponder: (UISegmentedControl *) sender
{
    NSArray *firstResponders = [self.responders filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UIResponder *responder, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [responder isFirstResponder];
    }]];
    NSLog(@"%@",firstResponders);


    UIResponder *firstResponder = [firstResponders lastObject];
    NSInteger offset = sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? -1 : +1;
    NSInteger firstResponderIndex = [self.responders indexOfObject:firstResponder];

    NSInteger adjacentResponderIndex = firstResponderIndex != NSNotFound ? firstResponderIndex + offset : NSNotFound;
    UIResponder *adjacentResponder = nil;
    if (adjacentResponderIndex >= 0 && adjacentResponderIndex < (NSInteger)[self.responders count])
        adjacentResponder = [self.responders objectAtIndex:adjacentResponderIndex];

    [adjacentResponder becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Bit lengthier,but this is all i know a BIT :)..Happy coding...